# Typescript: could not find a declaration file for module after using dts-gen

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, node-modules

I am using an npm package, https://github.com/SymphonyPlatformSolutions/symphony-api-client-node, that doesn't have types associated.

Directory structure

```
node_modules
  symphony-api-client-node/
    lib
      ...
src
  symphony-adapter.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

I tried to use dts-gen to create a type file, via `dts-gen -m symphony-api-client-node`. When I add this file, `symphony-api-client-node.d.ts` into src, I still receive an error for no declaration file for module `symphony-api-client-node`.

Based on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules, it should see the `src/symphony-api-client-node.d.ts` file and use that - is there something I'm missing here?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "removeComments": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "config/*"],
    "exclude": ["./node_modules", "**/tests"]
}
```

symphony-adapter.ts

```
import Symphony from 'symphony-api-client-node';

class Adapter {
  constructor(symphony: Symphony){
    this.symphonyBase = symphony;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
src/SymphonyAdapter.ts:3:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'symphony-api-client-node'. 'path/node_modules/symphony-api-client-node/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/symphony-api-client-node` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'symphony-api-client-node';`

3 import Symphony from 'symphony-api-client-node';
```

symphony-api-client-node.d.ts

```
/** Declaration file generated by dts-gen */

export function authenticateBot(SymConfig: any): any;

export function authenticateExtApp(): any;

export function authenticateOboApp(): any;

export function createRoom(room: any, description: any, keywords: any, membersCanInvite: any, discoverable: any, anyoneCanJoin: any, readOnly: any, copyProtected: any, crossPod: any, viewHistory: any): any;

export function createSignal(name: any, query: any, visibleOnProfile: any, companyWide: any, sessionToken: any): any;
...
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what it generates?

Comment: Updated in main post @AluanHaddad - it looks like a pretty standard TS file

Comment: Thanks for adding the file. There is nothing wrong with it but typescript isn't looking for third party type declarations under src. You can either use the paths or the typeRoots compiler options to inform typescript that those declarations are associated with the module you are importing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the contents of the generated `symphony-api-client-node.d.ts` file with

```ts
declare module "symphony-api-client-node" { }
```

For example: symphony-api-client-node.d.ts

```ts
declare module "symphony-api-client-node" {
  export function acceptConnectionRequest(userId: any, sessionToken: any): void;
  export function activateRoom(streamId: any): void;
  export function addMemberToRoom(streamId: any, userId: any): any;
  ...
}
```

Be aware that `dts-gen` is a starting point; you'll need to do some work to fix types (and the Readme for `dts-gen` says as much). For example, while many of the exported functions in `symphony-api-client-node` return promises, the generated `.d.ts` file will indicate return type `any` for most, if not all of them.